# Show Directory Browse Dialog in Firefox Addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to let my user pick a folder by showing a dialog.

Is this possible from JavaScript in a Firefox addon?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is an easy method of doing so.  The normal method is to use [nsIFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIFilePicker).

The primary difference from the example on that page is that in the parameters passed to the `init()` method, you specify `nsIFilePicker.modeGetFolder` as the `mode`. In addition, given that you are looking for a directory, you want to only include the `nsIFilePicker.filterAll` filter, and not a filter for a particular extension type.

Example code from the MDN page, modified for picking folders (and given descriptive variable names):

```
if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
    //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
    //  Add a "/" to un-comment the version appropriate for your environment.

    /* Add-on SDK environment:
    var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    //*/

    /* Overlay and bootstrap environments (from almost any context/scope):
    var window = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                           .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                           .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
    //*/
}


const nsIFilePicker = Components.interfaces.nsIFilePicker;

var filePicker = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"]
               .createInstance(nsIFilePicker);
filePicker.init(window, "Dialog Title", nsIFilePicker.modeGetFolder);
filePicker.appendFilters(nsIFilePicker.filterAll );

var pickerStatus = filePicker.show();
if (pickerStatus == nsIFilePicker.returnOK 
    || pickerStatus == nsIFilePicker.returnReplace
) {
  var file = filePicker.file;
  // Get the path as string. Note that you usually won't 
  // need to work with the string paths.
  var path = filePicker.file.path;
  // work with returned nsILocalFile...
}
```

Comment: I had to obtain a window with: `var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();` then everything worked, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I added some code which should work in all three types of add-on environments to get the most recent browser window. Could you take a moment and verify the code I added works in the Add-on SDK environment? It should work in all of overlay, bootstrap and Add-on SDK, but it would be nice to know that it definitely does in an Add-on SDK environment (already tested in the others). Thanks.

Comment: Since you used `Components` cfx is unhappy:

'...To do so, you need to add a
line somewhat like the following:

  const {Cc,Ci} = require("chrome");...'

I ususally try to avoid the `{...}` syntax since i stops eclipse from validating my javascript, but i think most of the people will have the shortcuts (Cc, Ci) etc. available, so you could use them.

Comment: Thanks.  It is now such that which code is needed in the three add-on environments can be chosen by uncommenting a line/section. My using `require("chrome")` for code with a better alternative did not appear to be the best choice. I encountered the same problem with eclipse and [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), actually anything past JS 1.5 (I use `let` routinely). Eclipse normal JS support did not look like it will be upgraded anytime soon (I checked the development code status 8-9 months ago).